# Starting with gpg under macOS

Tags: software-recommendation, encryption, gpg

I'm a Linux/Windows user but in the near future, I might have to support users running macOS on questions related to file encryption/decryption using GPG.  I have to provide support without having my own macOS to try...  I don't need to know the details, but I would appreciate it if someone could throw a few program names to help me get started on my reading.  Of course, Google returned some options, but I can't tell based on a web page if that is "the" most common way for macOS users.

My understanding so far is that within macOS' terminal, I can run the `gpg` command which is part of OpenPGP.  Is this standard on any "recent" Mac or does a specific software package have to be installed?

I came across the [GPG Suite](https://gpgtools.org/) which is commercial with a 30-day trial.  It seems that this is `gpg` with a GUI interface, GPG keychain, etc.  How is this option?  Is it common?  It seems equivalent in functionality to the [Gpg4win](https://www.gpg4win.org/) for Windows.

So far, these are the two options for users that I have found.  Have I missed anything?  And would this be the recommended options for GPG under macOS or am I completely off?  Thank you!

Comment: If you have to support Macs for a business then the business needs to supply a Mac - if ity does not then they are not making enough money off the service to be able to offer it.

Comment: @mmmmmm  Sure...  But, not all organisations operate as ideally as you suggest.  And while I could make a "demand", I think it's better to work within what I'm given and save my "demand" for something else that's more important to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you want GUI support, GPGSuite is the way to go.
- To use GPG in Terminal, install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) first and then use it to install the `gpg` package

Comment: I see!  That's enough to get me started!  Thanks for the quick response!